# Event call on switching to video mode - iPhone Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager

Okay, so I need to start an event when the user starts recording a video. 
I figured there would be an event for either starting a recording or switching to video mode but I cannot seem to find it anywhere.

Does anyone have an idea how to catch that event?

**What I want to do:**
I have a location based application and I would like to start a track that contains several locations when the user starts filming. This will later be stored in an sqlite3 database.

So I thought to catch either the "start filming" or "switch to video mode" event.
Anyone know how to handle this? Any better suggestions are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did your application implement the video view layout from `UIImagePickerController` class?

I assume that you have made some component like `UIButton` to fire capture video with method

`- (BOOL)startVideoCapture`

But you have to call your prefer method that base on your purpose like `start a track that contains several locations`

You can also see Apple's Document [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html). There are many interesting delegate implementation like

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker;
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I open the camera using `UIImagePickerController`. The user is however also allowed to take a picture in which case a single location is asked from the location manager. When I make a movie, several locations should be tracked and thus I need to know when the user actually starts filming rather then knowing when he finished. Are there any methods that I can use to catch this event? or catch when the user switches from taking an image to making a video?

Comment: I think there is no event or delegation to tell you while recording video.Do you would like to sent the information each location with time stamp in video record (such as "place 1 with 0:10, place 2 with 2:10"), isn't it?  Try to use `CoreLocation` Class for tracking user location while recording video simultaneously. Of course, you need to implement some timer object to start and stop at the same time with video.